# Firestore from Ruby - Could not load the default credentials

Tags: ruby, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get started with Google Firestore (FireBase) in Ruby and not really sure what to do about how to load credentials for server communication.

I am running this code from a test

```
it 'do something with firestore', focus: true do
  firestore = Google::Cloud::Firestore.new(project_id: 'jg-jai-dev')
end
```

and get the following error

```
RuntimeError:
    Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
for more information
  # /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@scraper/gems/googleauth-0.6.2/lib/googleauth/application_default.rb:61:in `get_application_default'
  # /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@scraper/gems/googleauth-0.6.2/lib/googleauth/credentials.rb:132:in `from_application_default'
  # /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@scraper/gems/googleauth-0.6.2/lib/googleauth/credentials.rb:90:in `default'
  # /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@scraper/gems/google-cloud-firestore-0.21.0/lib/google/cloud/firestore.rb:559:in `default_credentials'
  # /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@scraper/gems/google-cloud-firestore-0.21.0/lib/google/cloud/firestore.rb:507:in `new'
  # ./spec/services/export/firestore_job_export_spec.rb:220:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When I checked the documentation, it seems that I need to have some sort of credentials file in a JSON file but I am not sure where I find this file, I cannot see it in https://console.firebase.google.com

```
it 'where do I get the keyfile so that I can use Server authentication', focus: true do
  firestore = Google::Cloud::Firestore.new(project_id: 'jg-jai-dev', credentials: "keyfile.json")
end
```

Where do you actually get the **KeyFile.json**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install gcloud and generate a credentials file. The steps I took can be found in [quickstart-linux](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux) and [authentication/getting-started](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) but I have also listed them here.

1. Download and install gcloud

   - See: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux
2. Run gcloud

   - gcloud init
3. Select a default cloud project (not sure if this is needed)

   - At this stage I had the tooling needed to setup service account and create  keyfile.json.
   - I did need to exit the terminal and run it again before moving onto step 4.
4. Set up a service account using the command line

   - gcloud iam service-accounts create [NAME]

> gcloud iam service-accounts create my-service-account

5. Assign specific project permissions

   - gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT_ID] --member "serviceAccount:[NAME]@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/owner"

> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding jg-jai-dev --member
>   "serviceAccount:my-service-account@cool-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
>   --role "roles/owner"

6. Generate Key

> gcloud iam service-accounts keys create google-cloud-key.json
>   --iam-account my-service-account@cool-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com

7. Alter ruby code

Sample Code inside a spec test

```
it 'do something with firestore', focus: true do
  firestore = Google::Cloud::Firestore.new(project_id: 'jg-jai-dev', credentials: "./google-cloud-key.json")
end
```

Comment: A few things to ad...


1) You can create the service account and key file through the web console as well, if you don't want to use the CLI to do this. At the end you'll have a button to click to download the file.


2) Instead of having your source code specify the location of the key file, you can use an environment variable. If you set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the location of the file (ex. `/home/youruser/creds.json`, you can construct the client with `Google::Cloud::Firestore.new` (no arguments).

Answer (score 0):

According to [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/blob/d9308f4d70447899a7d66fa36e2ab7bf8339221a/google-cloud-firestore/lib/google/cloud/firestore.rb#L523) you have several options to create your credentials.

In your case your code should work. Try to put your json into `keyfile.json` in the same folder as a spec with `credentials: 'keyfile.json'`.

Another option is to create credentials object by yourself:

```
creds = Google::Auth::Credentials.new private_key: 2048
Google::Cloud::Firestore.new(project_id: 'jg-jai-dev', credentials: creds)
```

Comment: Hi Yzalavin, I will try your second option, but regarding the keyfile.json, I don't actually have one and I am wondering where it is found in the google cloud console